# Wrong time while Deserialize json object

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am deserializing List of class "pushNotification" using `JavaScriptSerializer` but I am not getting time values properly in result. However it is returned properly from the server side. I am using web http call to [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) to get list of this class. below is my code I get 6:00AM in "itemValue.ScheduledTime" however from service it was returned like 11 AM.

Datetime string returned from the server in JSON is "1425535200000+0500" and in datebase its "2015-03-05 11:00:00.000"

```
// Restful service URL
string url = "http://localhost:4567/ClientService.svc/GetPendingNotification";
string strResult = string.Empty;

// declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

// set method as post
webrequest.Method = "GET";

// set content type            
// declare & read response from service
HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

// set utf8 encoding
// read response stream from response object
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream());
// read string from stream data
strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<pushNotification>>>(strResult);

List<pushNotification> Notifications = new List<pushNotification>();

foreach (var itemValue in dict.Values.First())
{
    Notifications.Add(new pushNotification { Message = itemValue.Message, toAndroid = itemValue.toAndroid , toiOS = itemValue.toiOS, ScheduledDate = Convert.ToDateTime(itemValue.ScheduledDate), ScheduledTime = Convert.ToDateTime(itemValue.ScheduledTime)});            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JavaScriptSerializer` doesn't understand timezone offset. Use `DataContractJsonSerializer` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead (you'll have to mark object you're serializing/properties with `DataMember`/`DataContract` attributes).

Comment: how do i convert my current code which would be compatible with "DataContractJsonSerializer". i changed "JavaScriptSerializer " and its giving me wrong paramter issue.